# Scrolling through the taskbar pinned icons in Windows 11

Tags: windows, windows-11

After upgrading to Windows 11, I'm facing an issue in which I can't scroll through my taskbar pinned icons.

I have a lot of them, and it is shown this way on my laptop:
[image]

There is a list of icons, and all the rest go behind some kind of separator.
The problem is that I couldn't find any way to scroll through all the list, to get pinned icons that are hidden. It's extremely uncomfortable, and an issue that I didn't have in Windows 10, which I could scroll through.

Does anyone know a way to resolve this?

Comment: Look at Start, Settings, Personalization, Taskbar and look at the settings in Taskbar Corner Overflow. That may help you. Make sure the Taskbar is not locked.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? @john either you're mistaken or I'm mistaken. I've looked all over google and every response ignores the issue and responds to alter the unrelated icons that reside in the far right corner. The issue is the pinned icons between the start button and the corner. Unless I'm dumb and there is some setting called corner overflow for the main part of the taskbar.

Comment: There is no solution I can find that you are looking for

Comment: I also couldn't resolve it yet...